RUNDECK 5 org.rundeck.storage.api.StorageException: Not found
I installed the latest version of rundeck in docker. After transferring projects from the previous 3 version of rundeck, I have a problem with executing tasks on different servers.
After executing any task I get the message:
[2m2024-05-15T10:32:21,067ESC[m] ESC[1;31mm [36mnode.NodeStepPluginAdapterESC[m - Uncaught throwable executing node step.org.rundeck.storage.api.StorageException: Not found
[2m2024-05-15T10:32:21,830ESC[m] [1;31m [36mservices.ExecutionUtilServiceESC[m - Execution failed: 4726 in project LINUX-DEV: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [blockchain-dev-01: PluginFailed: Not found + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {blockchain-dev-01=[PluginFailed: Not found + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]

I will add information that on the rundeck server itself the tasks execute correctly, plugins are also installed. The nodes are imported into rundeck and in a given project they are displayed, however when it wants to add a new project and create a new job and select a node it only finds the rundeck server and does not see the other nodes. As if it does not find nodes in the docker itself
Maybe someone had a similar problem?
I thought it was a problem with the plugin but I checked with the previous version everything agrees is the same.

It seems that you're facing this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/8896, please check this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/8896#issuecomment-1962866596 (it seems a problem with old job definitions. Test editing your job and saving again).
